# How to assert to json objects in jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I created a post request in Jmeter, the response body from the request is in Json format and I want to do a comparison between the response that I have in a csv file with the response I have from the Jmeter request.
The response from the request is not sorted, two response have equal content even though they are not in the same structure.
An example:
post request, response body:

```
"getTestData":
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "London",
    "Data": [
       {
        "Oxford",
        "Picadilly"
        },
       { 
        "Kensington",
        "Central"
       }
    ]
}
```

csv file, each json response body in a row:

```
   "getTestData":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "London",
        "Data": [
           {
            "Oxford",
            "Picadilly"
            },
           { 
            "Kensington",
            "Central"
           }
        ]
    }
```

Can someone help me of how can I do the comparison between two? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your 2 snippets are identical
2. They are not JSON, you can check yourself using [online JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

---

In general it is better to use a special library, i.e. [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) which will make your life easier

1. Download [`jsonassert-x.x.x.jar`](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/releases) and put it somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) as a child of the request which returns the actual JSON response
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def expected = vars.get('expected')
   def actual = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

   org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, false)
   ```

   - You might need to change `'expected'` to the actual JMeter Variable name as it is defined in your CSV Data Set Config

That's it, in case of differences in JSON files you will get the error message stating where differences are.

Comment: Thanks, I done your changes but is still not working.  This is my CSV Data Set Config https://imgur.com/a/XhNnbSZ and this is the error I have https://imgur.com/a/qDtk2qH

Comment: what could be the problem?

Comment: It looks like you either haven't added the [jsonassert-1.5.0.jar](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/releases/download/jsonassert-1.5.0/jsonassert-1.5.0.jar) to JMeter Classpath  or haven't restarted JMeter or both

Comment: Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray. See log file for details. I checked the logs but still don't understand, what can cause the error. it instantly stops.

Comment: Try adding [json-20180813.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20180813/json-20180813.jar) to JMeter classpath as well

Comment: Now it started but in the assertion result it says: javax.script.ScriptException: org.json.JSONException: Unparsable JSON string: ExpectedOutput .. does it mean that in the csv file the json format is wrong?

Comment: Change `Expected Output` to `expected` in your CSV Data Set Config and leave my code as it is. It should work. Alternatively show your JSR223 Assertion configuration